# How to stop pptpd even when there are active vpn client connections?

Tags: vpn, daemon, pptpd

After issued command to stop pptpd, the pptpd won't stop until all the VPN client has disconnected. The following code shows pptpd is still running after issuing the stop command.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-138-31-87:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/pptpd stop
Stopping PPTP: pptpd.
ubuntu@ip-10-138-31-87:~$ ps -ef |grep pptpd
root      5524     1  0 21:46 ?        00:00:00 pptpd [<myIp>:8544 - 0000]                                                                                                 
root      5525  5524  0 21:46 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/pppd local file /etc/ppp/pptpd-options 115200 192.168.0.1:192.168.0.234 ipparam <myIP> plugin /usr/lib/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so pptpd-original-ip <myIP>
ubuntu    5564  4668  0 21:50 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pptpd
```

After all the active vpn client connections were disconnected mannually, the pptpd then stops.
Is there a way that pptpd can be forced to stop even there are active vpn client connections?

Answer (score 1):

Spend enough time to script it properly and you should be able to use the tcpkill or the cutter command inside of the init script so that connections are killed off prior to attempting to stop the daemon (assuming you haven't tried using kill command and that there is some form of autorespawn happening here which may be limiting its effectiveness).

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/cutting-the-tcpip-network-connection-with-cutter.html
http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/kill-tcp-connection-using-linux-netstat.php

Answer (score 0):

```
killall pppd
```

This will obviously kill all ppp connections including the pptp clients

In these days i think we all do not use ppp dialups so you will not risk interrupting any active internet conenction so this should o for you.

Or, you can do a

```
ps -aux | grep ppp
```

and get a list of pid's associated with the pptp connections and kill them manually one by one.